# Building a Javascript utility library with AMD compatibility

Tags: javascript, requirejs

My goal is to build a set of javascript tools for functional programming, to be used by our company's web developers. I've tried giving a look at the Underscore annotated source but I'm new with RequireJS and AMD, so it's a lot confusing for me.
To start I just want to have a variable that gets available when my library is imported. 
In this case booleans is a module that has functions returning boolean values. For example: _myLib.booleans.isDefined(var) - returns true is var is a defined variable.
No I have RequireJS setup, but how do I make a variable available for usage?
My *main.js*:

```
requirejs(['app/booleans'], function (booleans) {
        var _myLib = {};
        _myLib.booleans = booleans;
        return _myLib;
});
```

Of course _myLib is undefined, I suppose it's because it is not assigned to any scope.
Can anyone give me some lights on building this library?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to produce a proper AMD library, you need to set it so that it calls `define` to define itself as an AMD module.

```
define(['app/booleans'], function (booleans) {
  var _myLib = {};
  _myLib.booleans = booleans;
  return _myLib;
});
```

If you called your file `myLib.js` and provided a good configuration to RequireJS for it to find it, then, when you want to use it, you can do:

```
require(["myLib"], function (myLib) {
  myLib.booleans.isDefined("moo");
});
```

Or in another module:

```
define(["myLib"], function (myLib) {
  myLib.booleans.isDefined("blah");
});
```